# How input current affects circuit? Is it ignored?

Tags: current

All the examples I have seen so far, take the input voltage as-is and start calculating circuit current depending on on-board resistors using ohm's law etc.

Can you just ignore the original current rate? If it is doubled (say by using less resistant wiring) then it is double the electrons moving, it must have some effect, right?

Am i missing something?

Edit (1):

[image: example]

I am learning the basics, and everyone just seem to ignore the input current rating.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of what is actually being asked here. Please clarify.

Comment: There is no current in this circuit other than what comes from the input. Your question remains obscure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage source, which you drew, is an **ideal voltage source**.  It's a mathematical abstraction**.  You can imagine a caricaturesque character with a scroll and a trumpet proclaiming "The King said ten volts!"  Ideal voltage source will provide as much or as little current as necessary to maintain the voltage.  In the circuit in the O.P. (10V, 100Ω), the current will be I=V/R=0.1A.

** Especially if we take into account that the O.P. says that he's working through abstract examples.

The conductors, which you drew, are **ideal conductors**.  They have no resistance.  They can be 10mm long or 10km long.  It doesn't matter, because they are ideal.  If you want to see what conductor resistance will do to your circuit, replace the conductors with resistors, which have some value.

These are the things (abstractions), which the O.P. seems to be missing.

**update:** @elec_newbie
Well, it seems that you *want* current rating and can't do without it.  Here's a modified example for you.

> Assume the original circuit (10V, 100Ω).  Assume also that the resistor is rated for 0.25W.  What should the input current rating be?

Comment: Thanks. my confusion was with not understanding 1) ideal conductors 2) the circuit only draws what it needs (i assume because of potential difference?). Only thing left a mystery to me, is how many electrons (current yet again) affected by swinging a magnet over a coil, since faraday's law seem to give volts. Does it hide somewhere in the magnetic flux?

Comment: duh, looks like voltage is actually electric field and does not work on individual electrons, rather applies itself as they pass. voltage.askdefine.com has nice definitions. still unclear, how electrons passing through it affect it

Answer (score 1):

There are voltage and current sources. In the case of an ideal voltage source, the source maintains a constant voltage, and the load draws whatever current it needs.

\$I=\dfrac{V}{R}\$

In the case of an ideal current source, the source maintains a constant current, and the load voltage is induced by that current.

\$V=IR\$

Your example falls in the voltage source category. No one is ignoring the input current. They solve for it because it is determined by the load.

Comment: So is the input current states the max possible value, and the circuit only draws what it needs?

Comment: Are you talking about something like a phone charger that is rated say 5V, 1A? Yes, the 1A is a maximum, but putting \$1k\Omega\$ across it will only draw 5mA.

Answer (score 0):

All those examples you're talking about takes an input voltage and don't show input current for the sake of simplicity, but of course, input current is as important as voltage can be. Ohm's law speaks by itself. I cannot imagine a simpler answer to give you:)

Answer (score 0):

The examples you're looking at are assuming that the input is an ideal voltage source, which has zero internal impedance. Real world voltage sources have internal impedance (made of some combination of RLC) elements.  The current that flows between a source and load depends on the source and load impedance and the nature of the signal (DC? AC? What frequency?)

Ideal voltage sources are a useful tool because they let you think about the inherent response of a circuit in the absence of extraneous elements. An ideal source acting on a circuit is similar to a force acting on a body in a free body diagram in physics.

In the new diagram which was added to the question, there is a 10V voltage source, and a 100 ohm resistor. These two numbers determine how much current flows through the circuit: 10V / 100 \$\Omega\$ = 0.1A. Each node (junction point) in the circuit has 0.1A flowing in, and 0.1A flowing out.

There is no such thing as a voltage source which has prescribed current also.

Ideal voltage sources can supply unlimited quantities of current into any nonzero load while maintaining their voltage. Real-world voltage supplies cannot deliver unlimited current without either frying themselves, or losing their voltage regulation (allowing the voltage to drop). So real-world voltage supplies are accompanied by a current value which states their maximum limit.